# Can I move sprite more smoothly in AndEngine?

Tags: android, sprite, andengine

Here is my code.

```
MainScene pScene;
public ProgressBar(float pX, float pY, ITextureRegion pTextureRegion,
        VertexBufferObjectManager pVertexBufferObjectManager,
        MainScene pScene) {
    super(pX, pY, pTextureRegion, pVertexBufferObjectManager);
    this.pScene = pScene;
}

@Override
protected void onManagedUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed){
    super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
    this.mX += pScene.barSpeed;
    if(this.mX > 610){
        this.mX = 100;
    }
}
```

It moves well, but problem is that when I use this code, some sprites can never be at same place with this bar. (For example, when barSpeed is 7, sprite on (105, 30) can never meet this bar)

I need to move this Sprite more smoothly, which means it moves pixel by pixel, so this Sprite can touch all sprites. And this bar also must have codes that can control its speed.

Comment: More code pls. Do sprites move? Are you sure that your progresbar can be at needed place? Did you consider not checking exact position of the sprite but some range? (100 < x < 110)?

Comment: @ŁukaszMotyczka
It moves well, but problem is that it is moving not pixel by pixel, but like this.
if barSpeed is 5, it moves like (100, 105, 110, 115, 120, ... 605, 610, 100, ...)
So problem is that it can never meet with sprite on 103 or 104 or any other 'x's, and what I want is it can move 100, 101, 102, ... with speed I can coordinate.

Comment: I'm not sure if andengine can be any faster, because that's what you need. Right now on every update you progress bar moves. So maybe look into fps settings of your engine? Because you need faster updates. Or you can do that pixel by pixel but it may be slower movement.